# Do I need lock or mutex for shm_open

Tags: c, multiprocessing, ipc, shared-memory, shared-file

I would like to do multi-process programming where I need to share data (reader/writer case).

My idea is to use shared memory to track read/write index.
And the index indicates the shared file index.
For example, if write index = 2, it means writer is writing shared file named 
"temp_2.data". if read index = 1, it means reader is reading shared file named "temp_1.data".

My problem is:

1. **Do I need the synchronization mechanism when, ex: accessing rptr below?** **or shm_open itself promises the synchronization?** **If so, how it makes the** **synchronization?**
2. **The hybrid design of shared memory and shared file makes sense? Or if there** **is any better way?**

Thanks~

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
...


#define MAX_LEN 10000
struct region {        /* Defines "structure" of shared memory */
    int len;
    char buf[MAX_LEN];
};
struct region *rptr;
int fd;


/* Create shared memory object and set its size */


fd = shm_open("/myregion", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
if (fd == -1)
    /* Handle error */;


if (ftruncate(fd, sizeof(struct region)) == -1)
    /* Handle error */;


/* Map shared memory object */


rptr = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct region),
       PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
if (rptr == MAP_FAILED)
    /* Handle error */;


/* Now we can refer to mapped region using fields of rptr;
   for example, rptr->len */
...
```